# Programmatically modifying a custom UITableViewCell initialized from storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I designed a custom cell in the storyboard with 2 dynamic contents:

- a UILabel with text that can take 1 to n lines - variable size.height
- a UIImageView that should be positioned accordingly - variable origin.y

I have no problem returning the cell height and adjusting the UILabel, but I can't get the UIImageView to move.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [CustomCell heightFor:self.tableContent[indexPath.row]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell initWith:self.tableContent[indexPath.row]];
    NSLog(@"%f %f", cell.frame.size.height, cell.myImageView.frame.origin.y);
    return cell;
}
```

The NSLog returns the correct height for the cell, and the correct origin for myImageView, but the imageView stays in place.
Here's the method used to init the cell (defined in CustomCell.m)

```
- (void)initWith:(CustomModel *)model {
    NSInteger newHeight = [CustomCell heightFor:model];
    self.myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.myImageView.frame.origin.x,
                                               self.myImageView.frame.origin.y + (newHeight - kCellBaseHeight),
                                               self.myImageView.frame.size.width,
                                               self.myImageView.frame.size.height);
}
```

To sum up:

- heightForRowAtIndexPath returns the proper height based on the content of each cell
- cellForRowAtIndexPath initializes the cell properly, the height is correct, and the UIImageView inside the cell as a correctly adjusted origin.y

Still, despite all values being correct, the cell isn't drawn the way it should. This means that when the cell is bigger, the image is too high inside the cell, and when its smaller, the image is hidden by the cell below.

What am I doing wrong ? Can Auto-Layout have something to do with this ?

Comment: else? else for which if?

Comment: what are newHeight and kCellBaseHeight? haha i didn't even notice that else there!

Comment: meronix => no else, I just removed some of the code to simplify and left the "else"

Comment: newHeight is the result of the CustomCell class method heightFor: that determines the cell height given an instance of CustomModel. kCellBaseHeight is just a constant, the default height for the cell, which is its height in the storyboard

Comment: What are the properties of your image view - i.e, what's the content resizing mode, etc?

Comment: lxt: there's no content resizing for the image view. The label is resized, the cell is resized to adjust to the updated size of the label, and the imageview is just positioned differently based on the resize of the uilabel (if there's no txt to display, it's supposed to move up, and if there are multiple lines to display, it's supposed to move down)

Comment: Any frames you set under Auto Layout will be overridden when the constraints are applied. You can set the frame before inserting a view into the view hierarchy and that frame will be translated into constraints. So you could try removing and re-inserting the image view. Otherwise, you just need to accomplish this by manipulating constraints or turn off Auto Layout.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, that's why! Using constraints does work. I would accept this as the answer (if you care to elaborate on this other option remove/insert that'd be a plus).